# WPF Frame - The right way to load a page with a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application in which I want to load a page into a frame using buttons. I am wondering if this is the most elegant way to do it.

preferably I'd like to to all the page loading in XAML, but I was not successful,

I tried using:

```
<Button Name="StationButton" Content="Stations" Command="GoToPage" CommandParameters="View/StationPage.xaml"/>
```

But the buttons were disabled and I found no way to enable them.
So the more programatic solution seems to be as follows.

MainWindow.xaml contains:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Name="StationButton" Content="Stations" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Name ="ItemButton" Content="Items" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame Name="MainFrame" Source="Views/StationPage.xaml" />
            <StatusBar Grid.Row="1" Name="StatusBar"/>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The `Button_Click` method is:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        switch ((string)button.Content)
        {
            case "Stations":
                MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Views/StationPage.xaml"));
                break;
            case "Items":
                MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Views/ItemPage.xaml"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all the answers until now.
I Think I need to pinpoint to:
The button is not part of the frame or page to be loaded.
While being at lunch a thought came to my mind:

In the Button_Click method I am telling where the page should be loaded to (MainFrame). There is no such connection in the XAML code. How would the GoToPage command (which is a build in command) know where the page should be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

XAML, WPF and UWP are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other patters and programming approaches, doing so usually misses about 90% of the power of XAML. And runs into additional problems in every other place.

You rarely find a answer for cases where the MVVM pattern was not used.

A few years ago I wrote a introduction into MVVM. That should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: Christopher, thank you for your answer. I fact I stumbled over your article already, but tbh. I did not completely understand it yet.
I might need to add that these are my first steps in WPF or even Windows programming. 
While I was quite a keen procedural programmer some 40 years ago I struggle now a bit, so please be graceful :-), all I did was system administration in the last 30 years ...

Comment: “Josh Smith”, this doesn’t answer the question.  OP already indicated he tried to do it purely via XAML and commands.   Passing yourself as someone else is bad form

Comment: @MickyD: In MVVM the question would not be a question. The Command (that he button is linekd too) would expose some ViewModel calss on a property. The code behind of the view Side woudl register the prperty change event and display a Window accordingly. The moment I saw that Button Click I could that this was not properly implemented MVVM.